# What is the config location of elastic search? Where should the synonyms file be placed?

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, synonym

I want to use synonyms feature of elastic search . I don't know where to keep it. Need help!

Comment: How do you have installed Elasticsearch using zip or through repository(in case of Linux) ? Generally in CentOS config file location is `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

Answer (score 3):

You can place synonyms file in path relative to the config location.

You can have a look at [Directory layout](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/setup-dir-layout.html) of your ES setup.
It contains a `config` folder where you can place your `synonym` file and then specify relative path of that file.

For Example

```
    "filter" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt"
                }
            }
```

> The above configures a synonym filter, with a path of
>   analysis/synonym.txt (relative to the config location).

See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) for more detail

**EDIT:**

You can also specify absolute path. As per doc

> The path to the synonyms file should be specified with the synonyms_path parameter, and should be either absolute or relative to the Elasticsearch config directory.

Refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-synonyms.html)

Comment: For production code , why should the file be kept, there must be some other location where that file can be kept coz i dont see it as a nice practice,do u have know alternative to this

Comment: Do youknow where can I get a synonym file for the english language?